# Get permission for browsing \\wsl$\

Tags: windows, wsl2

I have Ubuntu running in `WSL2` on `Windows` machine. Trying to get to `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` file with win explorer:

```
\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\etc\ssmtp
```

But I can't get inside. Looks I need permission. How to get permission to Ubuntu folder.

Comment: If you navigate to `\\wsl$` you see something like [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/img_5d153f42bbbef.png?trim=1,1&bg-color=000&pad=1,1)? What build of Windows 10 are you running exactly?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

I installed `ssmtp` in one of my test WSL/Ubuntu instances, and I see that `/etc/ssmtp` is:

```
drwxr-x---  2 root mail       4096 Oct 20 15:17 ssmtp
```

This means that your normal user does not have access to the directory.  According to the Microsoft doc for [Accessing Linux files from Windows using \\wsl$](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions#accessing-linux-files-from-windows-using-wsl), this is explained with:

> Accessing Linux files via `\\wsl$` will use the default user of your WSL distribution. Therefore any Windows app accessing Linux files will have the same permissions as the default user.

Normally, this would mean that you *could* add yourself to the `mail` group to get access.  But it seems in my testing that WSL only uses the *primary* group membership (typically the group that has the same name as your username).  Doing a `sudo usermod -aG mail <username>` does not seem to work for this.

So while there *are* ways to get access from Explorer in Windows, they are all *really bad ideas* IMHO:

- `sudo chmod 755 /etc/ssmtp`:  Give all users read/transversal permission to the directory.  I do not know whether or not `ssmtp` will balk at this.  Some security-conscious software will.  Not that this is really a security risk on a WSL installation, but `ssmtp` doesn't know that.
- `sudo chown` the ssmtp directory to your username, which could very likely break `sstmp`.
- Set your *default* WSL user to `root` by creating a `/etc/wsl.conf` with:

  ```
  [user]
  default=root
  ```

  ... and then `wsl --terminate Ubuntu-20.04` and restart.

All of these will work, but you are better off just accessing it via `sudo` from *within* Linux.  There shouldn't be a reason you *need* access from Windows Explorer.